# iteration omits few elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I use the following code to iterate a response from a server and append it to the DOM.

```
var faqList = [];
if (resText.status == 'SUCCESS') {
    var faqChangeOffset = Math.ceil(resText.faqFeedList.length / 2);
    resText.faqFeedList.forEach(function (el, i) {
        var element = $('<div>').addClass('faq-question-wrapper').attr({
            'knowledgeArticleId': el.knowledgeArticleId,
                'type': el.type
        }).append(
        $('<h3>').html(el.title)).append(
        $('<div>').addClass('faq-answer').append(
        $('<p>').html(el.description)));

        faqList.push(element);

        if (faqList.length == faqChangeOffset) {
            $('.faq-container').append(
            $('<div>').addClass('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6').append(element));
            faqList = [];
        }
    });
}
```

The issue is, for an example `resText.faqFeedList` gets 7 elements. I want to split the result to 2 sections. I iterate the elements and append the first half of the elements.! but I couldn't get the second elements appended to the DOM. What am I doing wrong here!

Comment: where are you declaring `faqList` variable, are you getting undefined error? even if not then `if(faqList.length == faqChangeOffset){` is gonna get executed once

Comment: sry I edited the question. that is being declared earlier!

Comment: `if (faqList.length == faqChangeOffset) {` will ony executed once. you might want to try `if (faqList.length >= faqChangeOffset) {` for taking all second values. also no `else` part.

Comment: just add the appending of the second list of elements after the forEach statement?

Comment: None of the above solutions work! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `faqList.length == faqChangeOffset` for the first time, you add a single element to DOM and empty `faqList`. But in following iterations `faqList` doesn't get enough elements in it so it's length is never again equal to `faqChangeOffset` and thus the last code block is never executed again.

After the `forEach` you have the rest of the elements stored in `faqList`, so you can just iterate it and execute the same block of code right after `forEach` ends.

Something like this:

```
if (resText.status == 'SUCCESS') {
    var faqChangeOffset = Math.ceil(resText.faqFeedList.length / 2);
    resText.faqFeedList.forEach(function (el, i) {
        ...
    });

    // append the rest
    faqList.forEach(function (el, i) {
        $('.faq-container').append($('<div>').addClass('col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6').append(el));
    });
    faqList = [];
}
```

Comment: any way to bypass this bug?